# SQL Question: select cities distance without duplicates

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a table with the columns: city, x, y

I need to select the distance between all the cities without duplications
the results should look like this
city1,city2,distance

but 
I shouldn't get city2,city1,distance ( since I already got the distance between those cities...

what is the correct SQL query for that...
thanks!

Comment: Show your table structure. What are city1 and city2? foreign keys? strings?

Comment: Oracle, city1 and city2 are varchar2, x and y are numbers , no keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.City, c2.City, dbo.CalcDistance(c1.x, c1.y, c2.x, c2.y)
FROM Cities c1, Cities c2
WHERE c1.CityID > c2.CityID
```

Comment: Cross joins make me sad :(
...FROM Cities c1 JOIN Cities c2 on c1.CityID > c2.CityID please

Comment: Either way works really.  I felt the cross join syntax most properly conveys the potential performance disaster.

Comment: Thanks, is there a solution in case there is no CityId column?

Comment: @David this is not true, `FROM Cities c1, Cities c2` is just a form of CROSS JOIN

Comment: @javasuperuser: Use the CityName instead (or a combination of CityName/StateName).

It's definitely preferable to just have an autoincremented CityId column for performance and maintainability reasons.

Comment: @Imre L - what is not true?  In SqlServer - both queries produce the same execution plan.

Comment: @David B - I would also suggest using the ISO Cross Join syntax instead of the comma-syntax.

Comment: To All, this kind of rediculous inanity in the comments and voting is the reason I stopped answering SQL questions. 1. If you would do it a different way - make your own answer.  2.  If you downvote someone's answer (especially due to a typo), leave a polite comment explaining why - or if you have the rep, fix the typo.  It's not like the original answerer can't revert your change.  3.  Off-topic answers should not get upvotes, particularly when they just link to an article that you have to create an account on some remote site just to see.

Comment: Was commenting on you saying: "cross join syntax most properly conveys the potential performance disaster."

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    C1.city,
    C2.city,
    <distance calculation>
FROM
    Cities C1
INNER JOIN Cities C2 ON
    C2.city_id > C1.city_id
```

I left the distance calculation blank since it depends on whether you're doing "as the crow flies", using street routes, accounting for curvature of the earth, etc.

Comment: Probably duplication (someone else answered the same time you did), and you have an error in your version.

Comment: What's the error? I made an assumption that there was some kind of id (city_id), but that's not too relevant - it could just as easily be any PK column. If there is an error, then letting me know so that I could correct it would be the polite thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a "running total".

Be careful with triangular joins like `ON c1.CityID > c2.CityID`, they create an cartesian product! (I don't want to argue with anybody else's answer.)

Have a look at Jeff Moden's world best article about running totals:
[Solving the "Running Total" & "Ordinal Rank" Problems (Rewritten)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/).

If you don't have an account you will have to create one (only an email address is needed). However, I promise it's worth!